# Find lowest value in particular group

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

My Question is:

My database has 3 columns and has entries like this:

```
1|Tom   |1
2|Lucy  |1
3|Frank |2
4|Jane  |3
5|Robert|3
```

Now I want output like this:

```
1|Tom   |1
3|Frank |2
4|Jane  |3
```

Which means in each group(in this case third column) the lowest entry of first column.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I added the tag `greatest-n-per-group` (finding the lowest entry per group has a similar solution as finding the greatest entry). This question has been answered many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a correlated subquery with a group by.

One way to do this which is easy to follow is:

```
SELECT column1, name, column2
FROM MyTable as mt1
WHERE column1 in (SELECT Min(column1) FROM MyTable as mt2 GROUP BY column2)
```

But a better, cleaner way:

```
SELECT column1, name, column2
FROM MyTable as mt1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Min(column1) as minc1 FROM MyTable as mt2 GROUP BY column2) as mt2
ON mt1.column1=mt2.minc1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99e20/8)

Note: These two forms should be supported by most DBMS's.

Comment: I was searching on internet related to this query i found one more solution like                                                             SELECT mt1.*
FROM MyTable mt1 LEFT JOIN MyTable mt2
 ON (mt1.column2 = mt2.column2 AND mt1.column1 > mt2.coulmn1)
WHERE mt2.column1 IS NULL;                                             Can you please explain how it is working and what is the difference between this and using group by?

Comment: It's an alternative approach. It makes sense, but I guess it's a bit more cryptic. You can try it for performance.